# ResorceBundle from Map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, resourcebundle

I am trying to do my own implementation of ResourceBundle. I want to load texts from database.
I am stuck with something.

How do I create a ResourceBundle programatically from a Map object ?  The map object will have the internationalized texts based on the  locale.

Thanks,
Deibys

Comment: Make a [ListResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/list.html).

Answer (score 6):

It is very simple:

```
public class MapResourceBundle extends ResourceBundle {

    Map<String, Object> map;

    public MapResourceBundle(Map<String, Object> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
        return Collections.enumeration(map.keySet());
    }

}
```

After this, you can use `MapResourceBundle` (after you have initialized, of course).

Comment: Actually I want to use : ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME, FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot()
  .getLocale(), CONTROL)                        this will return a ResourceBundle  , in the CONTROL object , in the newBundle method , I  should create a ResourceBundle based on a Map object

Comment: Been looking for this. Thanks for the implementation. I changed it slightly not to require the map in the constructor, so that I can do `ResourceBundle.getBundle("my.custom.map.ResourceBundle", locale).getString(key);`, where `my.custom.map.ResourceBundle` is a class that extends `MapResourceBundle`. This way I don't get an exception due to the missing default constructor

Comment: @smac89 feel free to change the implementation, it is just a draft. You can add methods to manage the private map instance, e.g. make a copy, add values, or add a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be `ResourceBundle` specifically?  Spring provides a [`MessageSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) abstraction with various implementations.  The standard implementation is backed by a `ResourceBundle` but there are alternatives including a `StaticMessageSource` that you can populate from maps, and third party implementations [such as this one](https://github.com/synyx/messagesource) that are backed by a DB.